# Sum an RDD[Array[Int]] to RDD[Int]

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD of Array[Int] and I want the sum of all elements in each array in the form of RDD[Int].
What is the best way to achieve this

Comment: Welcome to SO ! and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @puhlen, this question is definitely not a duplicate, at least not of the one you propose.

Comment: @HristoIliev You are correct, I completely misunderstood the question.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a must read for newcomers: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5):

The answer may be as simple as

```
rdd.map(_.sum)
```